# Simple routing in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I don't undestand what wrong with my routing. Why does resource was not found if i define url pattern callback with app.js file ????

```
app.get('/myroute', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello  /myroute    from app.js')
});
```

```
var express = require('express');

/*var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');*/

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

/*app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);*/

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

app.get('/myroute', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello  /myroute    from app.js')
});
```

If i uncomment next lines:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

And put my url pattern callback to ./routes/index it'll work!

```
router.get('/myroute', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello / from /route/index.js');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this very interesting post https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/10/express-js-middleware-demystified/ you can find the next:

> Middleware is any number of functions that are invoked by the
>   Express.js routing layer before your final request handler is, and
>   thus sits in the middle between a raw request and the final intended
>   route. We often refer to these functions as the middleware stack since
>   they are always invoked in the order they are added

Hence if you want to handle 404 errors then you must put:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
```

after all the route handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the url module in your code? Because I cannot see

```
require('url');
```

in your provided code.

I just created a new node.js project, and include the url module. It seems working fine and I didn't see the problem your mentioned.

If this doesn't solve, maybe you can provide more specific error code?

Comment: yes, i used it. Just i'd not include probably not related code, as i thought. I might have found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I get it. it related to [passing request between middleware](http://expressjs.com/api.html#middleware) . So below if i call `next()` without arguments `res.send('Hello  /myroute    from app.js')` will be processed.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(); // early was next(err)
});

app.get('/myroute', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello  /myroute    from app.js')
});
```

Or would be better if put routing error handler below all routings.